# Reading 2 bytes from a file and converting to an int gives the wrong output

Tags: c, file, buffer, fopen, fread

Basically I have a text file that contains a number. I changed the number to 0 to start and then I read 2 bytes from the file (because an int is 2 bytes) and I converted it to an int. I then print the results, however it's printing out weird results.

So when I have 0 it prints out 2608 for some reason.

I'm going off a document that says I need to read through a file where the offset of bytes 0 to 1 represents a number. So this is why I'm reading bytes instead of characters...

I imagine the issue is due to reading bytes instead of reading by characters, so if this is the case can you please explain why it would make a difference?

Here is my code:

```
void readFile(FILE *file) {
    char buf[2];
    int numRecords;

    fread(buf, 1, 2, file);

    numRecords = buf[0] | buf[1] << 8;

    printf("numRecords = %d\n", numRecords);
}
```

I'm not really sure what the buf[0] | buf[1] << 8 does, but I got it from another question... So I suppose that could be the issue as well.

Comment: Make up your mind. Either you have a text file or you have a file with 2-byte binary integers. Not both at the same time.

Comment: @EJP I completely blanked and forgot that my int would be in ASCII form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number `0` in your text file will actually be represented as a 1-byte hex number `0x30`. `0x30` is loaded to `buf[0]`. (In the *ASCII table*, `0` is represented by `0x30`)

You have garbage data in `buf[1]`, in this case the value is `0x0a`. (`0x0a` is `\n` in the ASCII table)

Combining those two by `buf[0] | buf[1] << 8` results in `0x0a30` which is `2608` in decimal. Note that `<<` is the bit-wise left shift operator.

(Also, the size of `int` type is 4-byte in many systems. You should check that out.)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Is there another way I can somehow write the actual bytes from an int into a file so that I can test my program?

Comment: Try out `fprintf(file, "%d", numRecords)`.  This will convert `int` to corresponding text. If you want to write the actual bytes, you can do `fwrite`.

Comment: So I tried using fprintf(file, "%d", numRecords) and then I ran my code on the output and it now prints out 48... Do you think this is an issue with readFile()?

Comment: It's because `0x30` is `48` in decimal. I thought you were going to do `numRecords = 0; fprintf(file, "%d", numRecords;)`. If you want to write ascii number `0x30` to text file and want to see number `0` show up, you should do `fwrite(&buf[0], 1, 1, file)`. (assuming `buf[0] == 0x30`)

Comment: I did do numRecords = 0; fprintf(file, "%d", numRecords); . I don't want to write ascii, I want to write the actual bytes that represent 0 to the file. Because my algorithm is meant to read bytes, not ASCII.

Comment: What do you mean by saying that you want to write actual bytes that represents 0, but you don't want to write ascii? ascii code `0x30` is the actual byte that represents 0. Also `numRecords = 0; fprintf(file, "%d", numRecords);` did work on my machine...

Comment: Okay, so writing numRecords to the file worked, if I then look at the file it did write the number to it. But then when I read the first two bytes and convert them to an int and print that int, I get 48 (if the number is 0). I understand that this is 0x30 converted to bytes, but isn't the number 0, in byte form just 00000000?

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding. If you want to write binary data `00000000`, you should do `char data = 0; fwrite(&data, 1, 1, file);`. If you want to write 2-byte data of zero, that is, binary data `0000000000000000`, you should do `short data = 0; fwrite(&data, 2, 1, file);`.

Comment: Not a problem, you've done more than enough to help me. I tested it and it worked, so thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can directly read into integer

```
fread(&numRecords, sizeof(numRecords), 1, file);
```

You need to check `sizeof(int)` on your system, if its four bytes you need to declare `numRecords` as `short int` rather than `int`